# Ionic tab badge value not updating properly

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

This could be a misunderstanding of how Angular controllers work, but I am trying to understand why the badge values for my tabs are not being updated.

I have isolated the issue to a Codepen here: https://codepen.io/tyman7/pen/JKKEbO

Extract from HTML:

```
<ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home" badge="badgeValue" ng-controller="HomeTabCtrl">
    <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

Extract from JS:

```
.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope)
{      
  $scope.badgeValue = 1;

  $scope.updateTabValue = function()
  {
      $scope.badgeValue += 1;
  }
}
```

I ended up finding a solution that involves creating another controller that the badge value looks at. I have modified the isolated Codepen slighty to demonstrate: https://codepen.io/tyman7/pen/pbbRpb

Extract from HTML:

```
<ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home" badge="badgeValue" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

Extract from JS:

```
.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope)
{

})
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope)
{      
    $scope.badgeValue = 1;

    $scope.updateTabValue = function()
    {
        $scope.badgeValue += 1;
    }
}
```

The thing is, I just don't understand **why** it needs to be done this way. What fundamental knowledge am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You had multiple instances of the HomeTabCtrl. It created one when the 'tabs' state was entered and another when the 'tabs.home' state was entered.  Your 'tab' badgeValue was in one instance and the 'tabs.home' value another.  An Easy fix to the original is to change the name of the 'tabs.home' controller to 'HomeCtrl' instead and create an empty controller of that name.  Then the updateTabValue will be called in the parent scope and update the badgeValue throughout.

Here is a codepen:
http://codepen.io/stich12/pen/Nrrprd

Comment: I think this solution and my working Codepen are logically the same, no?

Comment: Yep your right.  just turned around a bit.  I didn't look close enough at the working one.

Comment: Knowing that they are two different instance helps clarify what's going on. Is there a way to reference an existing controller so I can avoid this? While it does work, it seems a bit awkward creating a new controller just to handle the badge value when that information is already available in the actual controller.

Comment: A state isn't required to have a controller.  You could just leave it off